# Post a selected value from a list via on click - PHP/HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-lists

I have the code:

```
<table>
<?php foreach (ListFiles('clients/'.$entry) as $key=>$file){?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $file;?></td>
<td><img src="pdf.png" height="40" width="40" alt="strategic report"></img></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

.. that generates a list of items within a table. I have added an button to right hand side in a different part of the table.

The question is: when a user clicks on the image, i.e. onclick, how would I get the value from the corresponding value/item selected?

I'm using PHP.

Cheers

Comment: assign an id to img , and then onclick use it to manipulate

Comment: I need to pass the value of what item is selected

Comment: sir that is what I just wrote , change this line for instance <img src="pdf.png" height="40" width="40" alt="strategic report"></img> to <img src="pdf.png" height="40" width="40" alt="strategic report" id="p" onclick="alert('pdf.png')"></img>

Comment: or could I just do this? <a href="nextPage.php?name=value"><img src="pdf.png" height="40" width="40" alt="strategic report"/>Click Me</a>

Comment: you can use that, no problem , but in test1.php do check for sql injection

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a unique ID for each item, and when the button gets clicked pass that ID to the server.

Comment: or could I just do this?    <a href="nextPage.php?name=value"><img src="pdf.png" height="40" width="40" alt="strategic report"/>Click Me</a>

Comment: if value is a unique identifier for the image, then it is ok.